# Android apk size increase in play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have a small android app (about 4 MB) uploaded into play store. However, a few of my users reported that the size was about 100MB on download. I could not gather a proper answer to this question, so I need help here. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should control your caching methods of your app. Users could talk about cached data of your application maybe

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun If it did not get clarified, I meant that the 4MB file it was supposed to download becomes 100MB on download.

Comment: can you share the link to the app?

Comment: @AngelKoh I could, But its only made available to my country. :(

Comment: did you add any other google libraries like google-services, firebase?    GooglePlay may auto update their google-play-services app (depending on your phones settings) . not sure if that update counts towards your app size or not. you may want to clarify with your users.

Comment: @AngelKoh I did use firebase analytics, fresco libraries too. Maybe it counts?